# An exercise from High Dimensional Probability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Given a stochastic process $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$ which has zero-mean, $\textit{i.e.}$ $\mathbb{E}(X_t) = 0$ for all $t\in T$. Suppose $\{Y_t\}_{t \in T}$ is an independent copy of $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$. Prove the following statement is true:
$$
\mathbb{E}\sup_{t\in T}[X_t - Y_t] \le 2\mathbb{E}\sup_{t \in T}X_t.
$$

I was doing exercise $7.1.9$ in the book [High Dimensional Probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf). While the upper bound can be done by simply mimicking the proof of Lemma $6.4.2$, the lower bound is somewhat tricky since now we cannot apply the triangle equality due to the missing of "norm".

N.B. The above inequality trivially holds if the increment of the stochastic process is always symmetric.

Comment: Are you missing $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @d.k.o. What I wrote here is not exactly the same as Exercise 7.1.9. I followed the hint, using the same symmetrization methods as in the proof of Lemma 6.4.2, and here I demonstrated the last step which I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I think the induced lemma you provided may wrong